# Generating a download link for an uploaded file using PHP

Tags: php, email

Using PHP, I have created a form which uploads and sends files via email. Now, the upload works perfectly and automatically sends an email to a specified email address. I'd like to include, if it's possible a download link for the file inside the email. I am able to send a link already but whenever I click on the link, all it does it open the file on the browser. I'd like it download when the link is clicked instead. The thing is, I am not connecting or saving the uploaded file to my database. I'm just uploading it on my server and sending it directly to the receiver. Is it possible to achieve what I'd like to do? If it is, how can I achieve this? Or do I need to create a database for it?

Answer (score 1):

You need to write file download code on that page where your link is pointing. From link extract the file name and write the following code

```
 if (file_exists($file))
 {
    if (FALSE!== ($handler = fopen($file, 'r')))
   {
    header('Content-Description: File Transfer');
    header('Content-Type: application/octet-stream');
    header('Content-Disposition: attachment; filename='.basename($file));
    header('Content-Transfer-Encoding: chunked'); //changed to chunked
    header('Expires: 0');
    header('Cache-Control: must-revalidate, post-check=0, pre-check=0');
    header('Pragma: public');
    //header('Content-Length: ' . filesize($file)); //Remove

    //Send the content in chunks
    while(false !== ($chunk = fread($handler,4096)))
    {
        echo $chunk;
    }
}
exit;
}
```

Comment: Thanks. This allowed create a url however, when I tried to download the file, I couldn't open it and all the other contents of my email, they're all text disappeared. why is this?

Comment: Where you have put this code? In your email content you don't need to change any thing. You need to put this code only where your link in email is poiniting

Comment: I'm not sure I get you. The form just reloads after I submit it so I added your code on the same file.

Comment: @user1597438 No you are sending a link in email.What is `href` of that link. I am just saying to put this code on that page where `href` of your link is pointing out. For example you are sending a link in email like `<a href="www.mysite.com/abc.php">Link</a>`. Now in your site put above code in `abc.php`